# the use of word 'guard' as a verb and a noun

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> 1. A guard is supposed to guard.
> 2. Guards used to guard.

Are these two sentences correct?

Is it necessary that we place the word 'security' before the  word 'guard' when it is already mentioned in the text that we are talking about protection and security?

Can we use a word that is a verb as well as a noun in one sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are grammatically correct, but pointless. They explain nothing of what the guard actually does, because you have used the verb-form to define what the noun-form does. It is unlikely to make any difference to the degree of pointlessness if you add 'security' to these sentences.

If you want to write a worthwhile sentence, you have to provide information or opinion. Depending on your viewpoint, you could say:

> Security guards generally sit around looking bored.
>
> Security guards act as a visible deterrent to anybody thinking of breaking the law.
>
> Security guards provide a first-level response to emergency situations such as fire, accident, illness or criminal activity.

Comment: Let's take an example of [Security guards generally sit around looking bored.] is it necessary that 'security' is written... without  this, will it make  sense, like in this... {Guards generally sit around looking bored.}

Comment: It depends what point you wnat to make. If your comment is specific to private security guards, you need to say it. If you want to say that **all** guards (army, police, etc) behave this way, you can omit it.